# Why some project templates are missing in visual studio community 2015 but appear in new project template search?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I want to create a new "WPF User Control Library" project I cannot find corresponding template under C# templates but when I type *wpf user control* in the search box **WPF User Control Library** template will appear among search results. I would like to know if that template is installed why I cannot see it without searching for it and if it is not available in visual studio community then why it appears in the search results?!

Answer (score 4):

The **WPF User Control Library** project template is available under **Installed>Templates>Visual C#>Windows>Classic Desktop>**